# No suitable constructor exists to convert from "char" to "std::string"

Tags: visual-c++

I'm new to coding in C and C++, and I have a program with
an issue. When I (try) to run it, it gives me this error:
"No suitable constructor exists to convert from "char" to "std::string".
I'm not sure what it means. My code is an example of a simple
substitution cipher covered in the book "Cracking Codes with Python" by Al Sweigart.
I just want to replicate it in C++. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream> // for communicating with user
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; // all symbols

string encrypt(string msg, string key, string mode) {
    string ca = symbols;
    string cb = key;
    string translated;
    if (mode == "decrypt") {
        ca, cb = cb, ca;
    }
    int index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < msg.length(); index++) {
        cout << "index is " << index << endl;
        int sindex = ca.find(msg[index]); // it works here
        cout << "sindex is " << sindex << endl;
        string cl = cb[sindex]; // the problem
        translated += cl;
    }
    return translated;
}


int main() {
    string msg = "";
    string key = "";
    string mode = "";
    string ciphertext = ""; // our variables
    cout << "Enter message: (no spaces please)\n";
    cin >> msg;
    cout << "Enter key (or \"none\" for using default):\n";
    cin >> key;
    if (key == "none") {
        key = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    }
    cout << "Enter mode: (\"encrypt\" or \"decrypt\")\n";
    cin >> mode;
    ciphertext = encrypt(msg, key, mode);
    cout << "The ciphertext is\n" << ciphertext;
}
```

For some reason it works with `msg` on line 17 but not with `cb` on line 19, even though
they're both std::string. The actual error is on line 19 with `string cl = cb[sindex];`.
Not even sure what's wrong. It works on line 17 `int sindex = ca.find(/*The thing here*/msg[index]);`.
(Maybe my Visual Studio 2019 has gone nuts.) If I replace `cb` with `msg` it still gives me the
same error. Maybe line 17 is a lucky line? Who knows? But *please* help, I'm so
**confused!**

Comment: It doesn't answer your question directly, but why not just eliminate the middleman? `translated += cb[sindex];` You could also use `string cl(1, cb[sindex]);`

Comment: I'm not sure how and why, but `translated += cb[sindex];` seems to work! Big Thanks!